# Create new fixed sized vector

Tags: rust

How can I create / allocate an uninitialized fixed sized vector in Rust? Here's how I would do that in Java:

```
int[] a = new int[128];
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked:

```
let a = [0, .. 128];
```

(via [Rust IRC channel](http://irc.lc/mozilla/rust))

Comment: Beware that in addition to being fixed size, this Rust array is stack allocated, which affects the lifetime.